# SQL-запрос с объединением таблиц и определением количества в разрезе

Tags: sql

Есть две таблицы: T1 (`contract_id`,`segment`,`branch`) и T2 (`contract_id`,`goods_name`). Требуется написать запрос, позволяющий выгрузить в таблицу T3 выборку полей: количество `Contract_ID` в разрезе `Segment`, `Branch`, `Goods_name`.

Вот то, что я писал:

```
Select segment, branch, goods_name, COUNT(*) as 'количество' 
  FROM T1 JOIN T2 ON T1.contract_id=T2.contract_id 
 GROUP BY segment, branch, goods_name
```

В этом случае возвращается таблица в разрезе всех трех столбцов. Можно ли вывести именно количество по сегментам, а остальные столбцы "как есть" в одной таблице?

Comment: Кому требуется написать запрос? Здесь не принято делать чужую работу. А помощь можно оказать лишь тому, кто что-то делает сам. Где Ваш попытка написать запрос самостоятельно.

Comment: В чём трудности?

Comment: Уберите `COUNT` получите объеденную таблицу, а если таблица второстепенна, то используйте вместо `JOIN` пишите через `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: добавьте пример исходных данных и желаемого результата

Comment: Укажите пожалуйста о какой СУБД идёт речь

Comment: И что значит '_остальные столбцы "как есть"_' Если вы группируете по сегменту, то для сегмента будет одна итоговая запись, но если для одного сегмента бывают два значения branch, то какое из них должно быть в итоговой записи ?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT segment AS name, COUNT(contract_id) AS co, 'segment' AS type FROM 
T1 GROUP BY segment
UNION ALL
SELECT branch, COUNT(contract_id), 'branch' FROM T1 GROUP BY branch
UNION ALL
SELECT goods_name, COUNT(contract_id), 'goods_name' FROM T2 GROUP BY 
goods_name
```

может так?